# Finding Equation of a Plane through the origin and the points$ (1, −2, 5)$ and $(8, 3, 2)$

Tags: calculus, vectors, 3d

Find an equation of the plane.
The plane through the origin and the points $(1, −2, 5)$ and $(8, 3, 2)$

I know $AB$ is $<7,5,-3>$ but I don't know what to do after that

Comment: What do you mean by $AB$?

Comment: Another way is to use the spawn of the two vectors $\alpha_1 u_1 + \alpha_2 u_2$ as equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vectors $\langle 1,-2,5\rangle$ and $\langle 8,3,2\rangle$ lie in the plane, so the cross product $\vec{n} = \langle 1,-2,5\rangle \times \langle 8,3,2\rangle$ is normal to the plane. Since the plane passes though the origin, the equation of the plane is given by $\vec{n}\cdot \langle x,y,z\rangle = 0$. Simplify $\vec{n}$ so that you write the equation of the plane in the form $ax + by + cz = 0$.

Comment: Why was this down voted?

Comment: @mvw hmm, something's fishy. For the past two days, I've been receiving downvotes on several of my answers with no explanation, when the answers are correct.

Comment: It looks like a fine normal-form equation to me.

Answer (score 1):

The general equation of a plane passing through origin is $w^T x=0$. $w$ is the direction of the normal to the plane. In your case the normal direction is in the direction of the cross product of the two vectors given, i.e that is the direction of $w$.